# Documents where the viewer can adjust features such as size colour font easily

Tags: pdf, font, color, accessibility, customization

I'm currently working on an assignment for teaching and learning strategies for students with a very broad range of disabilities that can inhibit reading literacy abilities. I'm thinking of an interactive PDF with audio to accompany text. However, because of the nature of my content I would also like the document to be presented in a format where the viewer can easily adjust font size, background colour, typeface in order to best suit their own visual needs. but I have no idea how to do this? any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to create something in the EPUB format using iBooks Author, Pages, or another app.  You can see how these allow the kind of flexibility regarding typeface/color/font size that you seek by just viewing one in the iBooks app.

[image]